# Can you find out when Google will next send Googlebot to crawl your website?

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, crawl-rate

I can find the last date when Google crawl of my website but I can't find the next crawl date.

Is there some place I can look to find out when Googlebot is scheduled to return?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking when Google will crawl your site again? They don't specifically state when they'll crawl your site, but they will, if it's reachable and you don't have it blocked.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Google [**Crawl Rate**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en) is determined by their algorithms. In order our website to be crawled very often we need to update the content of website frequently.

Google has [**Caffeine**](https://googleblog.blogspot.in/2010/06/our-new-search-index-caffeine.html) Update on June 8, 2010. This mainly deals with providing users with fresh results by crawling the websites with fresh content. Means they crawl the fresh content often and display the results.

But Crawl rate can be controlled in Google Search Console:

- On the Search Console Home page, click the site you want.
- Click the gear icon , then click Site Settings.
- In the Crawl rate section, select the option you want.

Now new crawl rate will be valid for next 90 days.

Following these methods will improve the Crawl rate:

1. Update the site content on regular basis to get site crawled frequently.
2. Host with servers of Good Uptime. Because **[Crawl Budget](https://moz.com/blog/relative-vs-absolute-urls-whiteboard-friday)** is important.
3. Create [**XML Sitemaps**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox) and submit to Google Search Console.
4. Avoid Duplicate Content.

Answer (score 1):

Googlebot crawls the web on a continuous basis.   It also doesn't crawl your entire site at once.   It may crawl some pages one day, some page the next, and some pages next week.

Googlebot doesn't schedule crawls of site, rather it schedules crawls of individual pages.  It may crawl your home page every day, but your deep pages every month.

The rate at which Googlebot returns to crawl your pages depends on how popular they are and how often they typically change.   Popular pages with lots of inbound links will get crawled very often.  Pages that change more often will get crawled more often.   A popular ever changing page like the CNN home page may get crawled every few minutes.  A backwater page on a less popular personal blog may only get crawled once a month.

When you make changes to your site, Google will see those changes over time.   Your more popular pages will likely get crawled more often.   Google will probably get to your popular pages within a week.   It may take a month or more for Google to recrawl your entire site.